# Apache ignoring max_execution_time when running a CGI script

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I have inherited perl script that gets executed via a web GUI (using CGI).  Without fail, the script quits at exactly 10 minutes every time.

I've updated the apache php.ini max_execution_time and max_input_time params to use a large number (3600 each), however, the script is still quitting at 10 minutes.

We're also using mod_perl, although I'm not sure if there are configurations somewhere that would effect limited run time.

This is all relatively new to me, so if there is other info needed I can get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `php.ini` file only effects PHP. Apache has it's own [Timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) directive. You can change this in your apache configuration file.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense.  The timeout is set to 300 though, and the script fails at 600.  I'll run a few tests to see if changing it helps.

Comment: The timeout change worked.  Odd how it ignored the 300s at first though.  Thanks again!